# Counting regions in a disk that has been cut by lines

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, induction, circles

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and $n$ lines drawn in a ring such that each one of them
intersects with all of them, but no more than two intersect at one point. prove that
the lines cut the disk $n^2+n+2\over
2$.

I can't figure out how to approach to question. Can you give me some hints ?

Comment: You should be able to prove the base case, $n = 1$. Now to help yourself, draw a diagram and count as you draw more chords.

Comment: Related: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/843834/35416) deals with lines intersecting the plane, which is very similar.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you already have $(n-1)$ chords in your circle, and you add the $n$th. It will intersect the other $(n-1)$ chords in $(n-1)$ distinct points, so it will be cut into $(n-1)+1=n$ segments. Each such segment splits *one* previous region into *two* new ones. So you added $n$ regions. Now show that this inductive step fits your formula, and also check the base case of $n=1$ or even $n=0$.